# (Powershell & C#) ExchangeOnline Cmdlets partially working

Tags: c#, powershell

The issue is a little awkward to explain but essentially I have a piece of C# code that connects & logs into ExchangeOnline via powershell (using System.Management.Automation.Powershell) from that I wish to run some more commands specific to the ExchangeOnline instance.

I've found that certain commands do not work such as "Get-Mailbox" or "Get-DistributionList". The error stream I have captured simply says the cmdlet does not exist. However if I try these commands in a powershell window it works.

The apparently problematic code I have running is pasted below (mix of both powershell and C#):

```
                string FullTenantScript = @"

[string]$SizeOfAllMailboxes = ((get-exomailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | get-exomailboxstatistics).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB() | measure-object -sum).sum


$TenantProperties = [pscustomobject]@{
    'Primary Domain' = Get-AzureADDomain | Where-Object IsDefault -Match 'True' | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    'Tenant ID' = Get-AzureADTenantDetail | select -ExpandProperty ObjectId
    'Number of users' = @(Get-AzureADUser -all $true).count
    'Number of Mailboxes' = @(get-exomailbox -ResultSize unlimited).Count
    'Number of Devices' = @(Get-AzureADDevice -all $true).Count
    'Number of Subscriptions' = @(Get-AzureADSubscribedSku).Count
    'Number of Distribution Lists' = @(Get-DistributionGroup).Count
    'Number of Dynamic DLs' = @(Get-DynamicDistributionGroup).Count
    'Number of 365 Groups' = @(Get-UnifiedGroup).Count
    'Size of all mailboxes' = $SizeOfAllMailboxes + ' MB'
}


$TenantProperties

";



            PowerShell getTenantinfo = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(FullTenantScript);
            Collection<PSObject> TenantInfoResult = getTenantinfo.Invoke();
```

I've read online that some of the older cmlets are being phased out (for example Get-Mailbox), so instead I use (get-exomailbox). I just don't get why I can run them in a powershell window but not in my program (as they should do essentially the same thing).

Please also note my program connects into Azure also (using Connect-AzureAD).

Any help or advice as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated & any further info required I will provide.

Thanks,
Mouse